# Disable check for override in gcc

Tags: c++11, gcc, gcc-warning

Is there a way to enforce gcc to ignore errors which result from C++11's `override`?

Explanation: I want to enable C++11 in a program. Unfortunately it misused some functions and macros from a library causing many `marked override, but does not override` errors. So I want to disable the error, just to check if there are more issues and then replace the errors step by step.

I checked the `-W` options, but they handle warings only. This is a real error.

Comment: Can you give an example of the source code of a method where the macros conspire to give the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hack you can use `-Doverride=` on the command line.  This will make it so GCC does not see `override`.

Comment: Effective & evil! made me smile.

Comment: Doing this will invoke undefined behavior if you are using the C++ standard library.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hack.  I don't know of any correct way to do this.